# Vue.js table sorting (HTML & Buefy)

Tags: javascript, sorting, vue.js, html-table

I'm using Vue.js in the current project. The situation is this: almost all of the tables use Buefy's  and have its built-in sorting (example below). I think that this is the simpliest way to do it. Documentation here: https://buefy.github.io/documentation/table

```
<template>
    <section>
        <b-table default-sort="user.first_name">
            <template slot-scope="props">
                <b-table-column field="id" label="ID" sortable>
                </b-table-column>

                <b-table-column field="user.first_name" label="First Name">                   </b-table-column>

                <b-table-column field="user.last_name" label="Last Name">
                </b-table-column>

                <b-table-column field="date" label="Date">
                </b-table-column>
            </template>
        </b-table>
    </section>
</template>
```

Then there is this one component in the project that is made as a normal HTML table (example below). The table data rows appear inside this Slot component.

```
<template>
  <table class="classname">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <slot></slot>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
```

The parent component of the above example is something like this (examplecomponent is the name of the component where the HTML table generates):

```
<div class="grid">
  <examplecomponent :class="exampleclass">
    <template v-for="(row, index) in filteredList">
      <othercomponent></othercomponent>
      <othercomponenttwo></othercomponenttwo>
    </template>
  </examplecomponent>
</div>
```

So, the question is.. What is the easiest/best way to sort the data in this situation? I tried to change the HTML table to use Buefy's b-table but it doesn't work well. My guess is that the parent component's elements must be changed too. There aren't any imports in .vue where the HTML table is, but the parent has all the access to the information that's necessary.

I'm a bit confused and quite new as a programmer, so I'd be happy if someone could help me out and explain everything in a detail like you'd tell a 5-year-old kid.

Comment: you want to sort each column manually or initially the table should be sorted with a given column?

Comment: The table should be sorted when you click the title/table header.

Comment: i could give you a solution using pure html and vue.js

Comment: I actually found the answer to my problem. Sorry that it took so long. I postponed this task a little. But thank you for your help. I post a part of the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved my own question myself but it took some time.

The easiest way might be emitting the click in  element like this (the place with normal HTML table, child component):

```html
<template>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th @click="$emit('sort', {column: 'Name', isAsc: !isAsc})">Name</th>
      <th> ... </th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</template>
```

```js
props: {
  isAsc: Boolean,
  sortedBy: String
}
```

And something like this would be inserted in the parent component:

```html
<child-component-name @sort="sortTable" :sortedBy="sortedBy" :isAsc="isAsc" v-if="yourTableSummary"> ... </child-component-name>
```

```js
components: {
  'child-component-name': NameOfYourComponent
},

data() {
    return {
        isAsc: true,
        sortedBy: 'Name'
        yourTableSummary: {}
    }
},

methods: {
    sortTable({column, isAsc}) {
        // Set isAsc to default if sorted column changes
        if (column != this.sortedBy) {
            isAsc = true
        }

        let sortedList = []
        if (isAsc) {
            sortedList =
                this.yourTableSummary.Rows.sort((a, b) => {
                    return a[column].localeCompare(b[column])
                })
        } else {
            sortedList =
                this.yourTableSummary.Rows.sort((a, b) => {
                    return (a[column].localeCompare(b[column]) * -1 )
                })
        }

        this.yourTableSummary.Rows = [...sortedList]
        this.sortedBy = column
        this.isAsc = isAsc
    },
}
```